# jQuery / JS rolling numbers one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function which fires numbers to roll from 0 to X. i also made it to start only when i mouseover on specific DIV. all works fine.

however i want each number to roll separately one after another.

first, next, next, next etc.

how do i implement it it to this code

```
   $( ".skaic" ).one( "click mouseover", function() {
      $('.Count').each(function () {
          $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
              Counter: $(this).text()
          }, {
              duration: 3000,
              easing: 'swing',
              step: function (now) {
                  $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
              }
          });
      });
    });
```

**Markup:**

```
<div class="skaic">
    <span class="Count">5</span>
    <span class="Count">2</span>
    <span class="Count">12</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to post an example of the HTML as well, as you have to target each `.Count` related to the `.skaic` element, not all of them

Comment: never simpler <div class="skaic"><span class="Count">5</span><span class="Count">2</span><span class="Count">12</span></div>

Comment: thanks @adeneo. this worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a delay in the loop

```js
$(".skaic").one("click mouseover", function() {
    $('.Count').each(function(i) {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).delay(i*3000).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function(now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.Count {
    display: block;
    font-size : 30px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skaic">
    <span class="Count">5</span>
    <span class="Count">2</span>
    <span class="Count">12</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is elegant solution. Can we also do this using deferred?